# Creating new content types (Pages, posts, testimonials, tigers, oh my!)

Tags: templates

I have a blog on my WordPress site but I have a different type of content that I want to organize in a similar way: a collection of curated media content for language learners. The blog structure's tag feature would be very helpful.

I see that there are multiple content types. How does one create their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)